# How can I make youtube-dl return the creator of a playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, jq

I can use `youtube-dl` with the `--dump-json` option and `jq` to get the uploader of a *video*:

```
uploader=$(youtube-dl --dump-json "$video_url" | jq -r '.uploader')
```

Is there a way to get the creator of a *playlist* in a similar way?

```
youtube-dl -j "$playlist_url"
```

returns a list of videos but no information about the playlist creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Seth suggests in his answer I can use the `--skip-download` and `--output` options. Experimenting a bit I figured out that the --output option will not put any extra info in the json data. However, calling `youtube-dl` like this:

```
youtube-dl --skip-download --playlist-end 1 --output '%(playlist_uploader)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' "$playlist_url"
```

does create a folder with the name of the playlist uploader. This folder I can the get using the `find` command like so:

```
find . -type d -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561987/2737125) answer to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory) at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com). This is even more roundabout than what @Seth suggests but it does solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat round about but you could include it in the output name or similar as it seems to be a supported variable.

[Readme](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/de/de/ark/products/126687/intel-core-i5-8400-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html)

> - playlist (string): Name or id of the playlist that contains the video
> - playlist_index (numeric): Index of the video in the playlist padded with leading zeros according to the total length of the playlist
> - playlist_id (string): Playlist identifier
> - playlist_title (string): Playlist title
> - playlist_uploader (string): Full name of the playlist uploader
> - playlist_uploader_id (string): Nickname or id of the playlist uploader

Using `--external-downloader` you might be able to use a script. Depending on the output you might also be able to use `--skip-download` or `--simulate`. In Theory using the variable in `-o` should include it in the json.